# Reutilizar computed properties em Vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Tenho um cálculo de totais de certos valores em uma paginação. Este cálculo está em uma [*computed property*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) inserida em um componente. O problema que possuo outro componente semelhante que precisa utilizar a mesma [*computed property*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties). Segue parte do código abaixo referente apenas ao cálculo dos totais (se desejarem posso postar o componente por completo):

```
// ... dentro de methods
  vlr (param) {
    let today = new Date()
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    let venc = new Date(param.ven)
    venc.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

    if (venc.getTime() >= today.getTime()) {
      return parseFloat(param.total)
    }

    return param * 0.02
  }
},
computed: {
  getTotal (param) {
    let total = {}
    if (param.length) {
      param.forEach(idx => {
        idx.vlr = this.vlr(idx)
        Object.keys(idx).forEach(key => {
          if (!total[key]) {
            total[key] = {
              counter: 0,
              sum: 0,
              values: [],
              uniqueCounter: 0
            }
          }

          total[key].counter += 1
          total[key].sum += idx[key]

          if (total[key].values.indexOf(idx[key]) === -1) {
            total[key].uniqueCounter += 1
            total[key].values.push(idx[key])
          }
        })
      })
    }

    return total
  }
}
```

Minha dúvida é exatamente esta. Como reutilizar de forma eficiente uma *computed property*?

Tentei utilizar com [*mixins*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#ad), porém não obtive sucesso até o momento para esta situação.

Observação: O código foi feito com ESLint.

Comment: Queres partilhar valores em runtime, ou somente queres ser mais DRY e ter o código partilhado pelos dois componentes?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, seria a segunda opção.

Comment: Utilize o conceito de **bus**. É minha opnião. No seu **App.vue**, dentro do **created**, chame um method (bus.$on('methodname')) aonde faz o cálculo. E dentro de seus componentes dá um **$emit** (utilizando o **bus**) passando os valores. O **$emit** pode, inclusive, ficar dentro do computed.